# Shuffle a LinkedList

Tags: c#, algorithm, linked-list

I have a custom `LinkedList` class with a shuffle method. To me it looks correct but the results seem to be not really shuffled.

```
public class LinkedList<T>
{
    public class Node<T>
    {
        public T data;
        public Node<T> next;
    }

    private Node<T> _lastNode;
    private Node<T> _headNode;
    private int _count;
}
```

**example:**

input: `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8`

output 1: `2,1,8,6,7,4,5,3`

output 2: `2,1,8,7,5,6,4,3`

output 3: `2,1,7,8,6,5,3,4`

i know `Random` uses DateTime so i waitet a few seconds between the different results. I guess there is a thinking error in the shuffle method?

**shuffle method:**

```
public void Shuffle()
{
    if (_headNode != null)
    {
        Random Rand = new Random();
        Node<T> nLast = _lastNode;          
        Node<T> nFirst = _headNode;

        foreach (Node<T> item in Nodes)
        {
            T dTemp = item.data;
            if (Rand.Next(0, 2) == 0)
            {
                item.data = nLast.data;
                nLast.data = dTemp;
            }
            else
            {
                item.data = nFirst.data;
                nFirst.data = dTemp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

basicly I iterate through the LinkedList and exchange the current value with the first / last node's value

**question:** is there a error in my approach? Or is there even a other algorithm better for sorting a `LinkedList`?

Comment: Use the [Fisher-Yates algorithm](https://gist.github.com/mikedugan/8249637) instead. That should still work even though you are moving the values, rather than the items.

Comment: @stuartd - i've implemented the FY algorithm but it's much slower than the first approach. `LinkedList` isn't designed for acces by index

Comment: They look shuffled to me. What makes you think that they're not shuffled "enough"?

Comment: The only other suggestion I have is to move the creation of your random number generation **outside** the shuffle method. Just do it once when your application starts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the **"inside-out" version** of the [Fisher–Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) can be adjusted for your case.

```
public void Shuffle(Random random = null)
{
    if (_count < 2) return;
    if (random == null) random = new Random();
    var result = new Node[_count];
    int i = 0;
    for (var node = _headNode; node != null; node = node.next)
    {
        int j = random.Next(i + 1);
        if (i != j)
            result[i] = result[j];
        result[j] = node;
        i++;
    }
    _headNode = _lastNode = result[0];
    for (i = 1; i < result.Length; i++)
        _lastNode = _lastNode.next = result[i];
    _lastNode.next = null;
}
```

The first pass populates a shuffled node array, then the second pass updates the links, ending up with **O(N)** time and space complexity.

Test:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Tests
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var list = new LinkedList<int>();
            for (int n = 1; n <= 8; n++)
                list.Add(n);
            Action<string> dump = info => Console.WriteLine("{0,-10}({1})", info, string.Join(",", list.Nodes.Select(n => n.data.ToString())));
            dump("Input");
            var random = new Random();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                list.Shuffle(random);
                dump("Output " + i);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class LinkedList<T>
    {
        public class Node
        {
            public T data;
            public Node next;
        }

        private Node _lastNode;
        private Node _headNode;
        private int _count;

        public void Add(T data)
        {
            var node = new Node { data = data };
            if (_lastNode != null) _lastNode.next = node; else _headNode = node;
            _lastNode = node;
            _count++;
        }

        public IEnumerable<Node> Nodes { get { for (var node = _headNode; node != null; node = node.next) yield return node; } }

        public void Shuffle(Random random = null)
        {
            if (_count < 2) return;
            if (random == null) random = new Random();
            var result = new Node[_count];
            int i = 0;
            for (var node = _headNode; node != null; node = node.next)
            {
                int j = random.Next(i + 1);
                if (i != j)
                    result[i] = result[j];
                result[j] = node;
                i++;
            }
            _headNode = _lastNode = result[0];
            for (i = 1; i < result.Length; i++)
                _lastNode = _lastNode.next = result[i];
            _lastNode.next = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Input     (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
Output 1  (6,4,8,5,7,2,3,1)
Output 2  (4,1,2,6,3,8,7,5)
Output 3  (6,7,8,2,1,5,4,3)
Output 4  (7,1,6,5,8,4,3,2)
Output 5  (1,7,6,4,8,5,3,2)
Output 6  (6,7,1,4,5,2,3,8)
Output 7  (1,7,6,8,5,2,4,3)
Output 8  (3,8,5,7,6,4,2,1)
Output 9  (5,2,3,6,7,4,1,8)
Output 10 (3,7,4,6,8,2,1,5)
```

Comment: Props on writing out the code that I was too lazy to do. This answer could be improved if you were to include why that algorithm is better than what he is currently doing, feel free to take from mine if you think that my analysis is correct.

Comment: @KevinWells Thank you. I think there is enough info on the subject, including the link in the answer as well as your analysis. So rather than repeating it, I'm just going to upvote yours:)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your shuffling algorithm isn't particularly good at shuffling. If I understand it correctly you are looking at each element, and then swapping it with either the first or last element. The major problem is that that only leaves a small handful of possible ending states. Mathematically it only gives two options for each item in the list or `2^n` possibilities. That is not even counting any potential duplicate outcomes which would further reduce the number of options, but I don't want to work out how many of those there are. The total possible options for a shuffled set is `n!`.

In your case you have 10 items, so your algorithm gives `2 ^ 10 = 1024` possible outcomes, whereas there is a total of `10! = 3628800` actual possibilities. If you implement a better algorithm you will see more diverse outcomes. For example, here is a possible algorithm that would be better.

Pick a random number between `1` and `n`, remove that element from the starting list and add it as the first element in the shuffled list, then repeat this process with a number between `1` and `n-1` (since the starting list is now one element smaller). Do that until you are out of elements in the starting list. That gives all of the possible outcomes for a shuffled list, and the outcome doesn't depend at all on the order of the starting list. There is also a way to do this in place if memory is a concern, and if you want I can write up pseudo code showing you how that would work

p.s. if someone sees an issue with my calculations let me know and I'll fix it

Edit: I just realized that you are doing this on a `LinkedList` and not a `List`, but I'm sure the same algorithm could be applied, or you could convert your `LinkedList` into a `List` before doing the shuffle